# In Spacemacs, how can I enable snippets without having an autocomplete popup/completion?

Tags: spacemacs, yasnippet, auto-complete-mode

I'm using the [auto-completion layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/+completion/auto-completion) in Spacemacs with the following configuration:

```
(auto-completion :variables
                 auto-completion-return-key-behavior nil
                 auto-completion-tab-key-behavior nil
                 auto-completion-complete-with-key-sequence nil)
```

I'd like to not have auto-completion at all and instead just have snippets. Is there a way to disable the popup and in-place completion that comes with the layer while keeping snippets? Examples of the popup and the completion follow.

[image: Popup.] [image: Completion.]

It may not be clear from the completion pic but the "ass" part is added by the auto-completion layer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable this behavior with the variable:

auto-completion-minimum-prefix-length

By setting it to some ridiculously high value, this effectively disables the pop-up.

```
auto-completion
         (auto-completion :variables
               auto-completion-minimum-prefix-length 30
               )
```

I can still call templates calling helm-yas (default: space i s) but I'm not sure if this breaks expansion in insert mode as I don't use it.

EDIT: I just learned this doesn't break snippet expansion in insert mode. `M-/` calls `Hippie-expand` just fine.